# Can Kummer theory - there exists some $\gamma$, $L=K(\gamma^{1/n})$ - really be applied to any abelian extension $L/K$ (in characteristic zero, say)?

Tags: galois-theory, abelian-groups, radicals, galois-extensions, kummer-theory

$\newcommand{\gal}{\operatorname{Gal}}\newcommand{\char}{\operatorname{char}}$I recently learnt a little about Kummer extension from [Professor Borcherd's lecture](https://youtu.be/UaeJNQ5x17g) and from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer_theory). Wikipedia and other sources seemed to be saying that in general, a Galois extension $L/K$ is abelian iff. it is generated by some $n$th root, if one presumes:

- $K$ contains *distinct* $n$th roots of unity (in particular, $\char K\nmid n$)
- $\gal(L/K)$ is a group of exponent $n$

Wikipedia and Borcherds both prove that Kummer extensions are given by taking $n$th roots for extensions $L/K$ for which $\gal(L/K)\cong\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ for some prime $p$. The most general case of any abelian group is not covered.

I thought I had a solution to this. If $\gal(L/K)$ is taken to be abelian, then all subgroups are normal and all quotients exist. So, in a simple case, let's say $|\gal(L/K)|=p^3$ for some prime $p$. By Cauchy's theorem, there is an element $\sigma_1$ of order $p$, and I can consider $H_1:=\langle\sigma_1\rangle$ a normal subgroup. By a basic theorem of Galois theory, then the fixed field $K^{H_1}$ is a Galois extension of $K$, and $\gal(L/K^{H_1})=H_1$ and $\gal(K^{H_1}/K)\cong\gal(L/K)/H_1$ which has order $p^2$. By the theorem for abelian extensions of order $p$ (automatically cyclic) and presumption on $K$ containing all $p^3$th roots of unity, $K$ also contains all $p$th roots of unity - so does $K^{H_1}$, of course - so $L=K^{H_1}(\sqrt[p]{\gamma_1})$ for some element $\gamma_1\in K^{H_1}$.

We can induct - again by Cauchy's theorem, there is some order $p$ element in $\gal(K^{H_1}/K)$, call it $\sigma_2$, so we can consider the normal subgroup $H_2:=\langle\sigma_2\rangle$. Then $K^{H_2}$ is a Galois extension of $K$, and $K^{H_1}=K^{H_2}(\sqrt[p]{\gamma_2})$ for some element $\gamma_2\in K^{H_2}$, and $\gal(K^{H_2}/K)\cong\gal(K^{H_1}/K)/H_2$ which has order $p$, so is cyclic itself with some generator $\sigma_3$. Finally, $K^{H_2}=K(\sqrt[p]{\gamma_3})$ for some $\gamma_3\in K$, and I conclude: $$L=K^{H_1}(\sqrt[p]{\gamma_1})=\cdots=K(\sqrt[p]{\gamma_3})(\sqrt[p]{\gamma_2})(\sqrt[p]{\gamma_1})$$Somehow we can combine this into a $p^3$-root of some $\gamma\in K$ (edit: actually no we can’t in general) but I'm not completely confident on how to do this. Wikipedia take a large product, but that feels wrong to me. $\gamma_2$ is some combination in $\sqrt[p]{\gamma_3}$, etc., so I suppose one just replaces all instances of $\gamma_{1,2}$ with their expressions in $\gamma_3$, finally leaving one with one single root of size $p^3$.

**My main question** - is that correct? Does it generalise in the way I hope to, say, when the exponent of $\gal(L/K)$ is some product of primes, say $p_1^3p_2^2$? I think one can use the structure theorem to reduce to the cases where there is only one prime power present, but I'm not sure.

---

As an aside, I'd appreciate a solution-verification on what I've done below.

> I tried to apply this on a specific example, to see if it really worked. Consider $K=\Bbb Q$, $L=\Bbb Q(\alpha=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})$. This has a Galois group which is cyclic of order $4=2^2$, generated by $\sigma$ which maps $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\mapsto\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$. To begin the induction, I take the subgroup $H_1=\langle\sigma^2\rangle$. We follow the eigenvalue/eigenvector algorithm - the second roots of unity are just $\pm1$, so we take the eigenvector with value $-1$. Take the root $\alpha$ and construct $v_1=\alpha-\sigma^2(\alpha)$. According to the Kummer theory, $v_1^2$ should be an element of $K^{H_1}$. This is easily seen, and in fact $v_1=2\alpha$, so $v_1^2=4\alpha^2=8+4\sqrt{2}$, which agrees with our prior knowledge since we know $K^{H_1}=K(\sqrt{2})$. Then the theory claims $L=K^{H_1}(\sqrt{8+4\sqrt{2}})=K^{H_1}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})$ by bringing out the factor of $2^2$ as it is irrelevant. So far, so good. The group $\gal(K^{H_1}/K)$ is harder to determine (pretending we don't have the full knowledge already) - according to my notes, it is given by the restriction map $\gal(L/K)\to\gal(K^{H_1}/K)\cong\gal(L/K)/H_1$. Then I think the order two element of this group should just be the restriction of $\sigma|_{K^{H_1}}$. So, following the same process, we pick a value in $K^{H_1}\setminus K$, say $\beta=v_1^2$, and construct $v_2=\beta-\sigma(\beta)$. The claim would be that $v_2^2\in K$, which is true. $v_2=8\sqrt{2}$ and $v_2^2=128$.
>
> Then according to the theory, $L=K(\sqrt{128})(\sqrt{8+4\sqrt{2}})=K(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})$, which is true.

My second question - did I do that correctly? I know the conclusion is correct, but I feels like I've not done something "properly" since I was only able to compute these values with my prior knowledge of all the roots and what $\sigma$ is. Is it even possible to use this theory to find the (nested) radicals without exact knowledge of the elements of the Galois group?

Comment: Nevermind, you were only trying to prove the result by induction on the exponent. I read carelessly.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If I had all roots of unity of order $p^3$ it would contain the exponent in all situations, right? Really, I just want to know if the extensions are always constructive by adjoining a root

Comment: I mean a radical, not just any old root

Comment: Are you trying to prove that any abelian extension is cyclic? I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're trying to prove, but it is definitely not true that taking only one $n$th root is enough, unless the extension is cyclic. And that is clearly not what is said on the wikipedia page (I did not check Borcherd's notes but I'm confident he doesn't say that either). Rather, the extension is generated by a finite number of $n$th roots.

Comment: @CaptainLama I’m not trying to say any abelian extension is cyclic and certainly it is false in general. I’m trying to understand the idea that abelian extensions can be broken down into a sequence of radical extensions, which you seem to have now confirmed! Do you agree with my reasoning / process for finding these radical extensions via induction? You see, I haven’t been able to find general resources on this so I had to make it up myself, hence the anxiety

Comment: Another silly remark. Kummer theory does not promise that the extension is gotten by adjoining a *single* $n$th root. There may be many. Like $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)/\Bbb{Q}$, which is a degree eight extension with an abelian Galois group of exponent two, hence generated by square roots of rational numbers.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Hmm. I’m very interested in what Kummer theory *does* promise, because that wasn’t clear to me, with Wikipedia mentioning single $n$th roots in some cases but not in others (without explanation why, or what is the replacement)

Comment: Wikipedia says that (in the case of exponent $n$ and the smaller field containing $n$th roots of unity) you adjoin the $n$th roots of a (multiplicative) subgroup $\Delta\le K^*/K^*n$. In the above example $\Delta$ is the subgroup $\langle 2,3,5\rangle$. Read Wikipedia's definition of $\Delta^{1/n}$ carefully. It is a set of elements, not a single element. We adjoin $\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,\sqrt{2\cdot3}$ etc, but, of course, it suffices to adjoin the roots of the generators of $\Delta$.

Comment: What Kummer promises may perhaps be better understood, when we don't have the required roots of unity. For example $\Bbb{Q}(2\cos(2\pi/7))$ is a cubic cyclic Galois extension of $\Bbb{Q}$, but you cannot get it by adjoining a cube root. This is all fine as $\Bbb{Q}$ does not contain third roots of unity. On the other hand with $K=\Bbb{Q}(\omega),\omega=e^{2\pi i/3},$ the extension $K(2\cos(2\pi/7))/K$ can also be gotten by adjoining a cube root. The usual process shows that the eigenvector
$$z=2\cos(2\pi/7)+\omega2\cos(4\pi/7)+\omega^22\cos(8\pi/7)$$ has its cube  $z^3=14+21\omega\in K$.

Comment: Sorry about reposting the previous comment. I was editing it, but then the service became unavailable to me.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No worries, thanks for all your comments, it has clarified some points